# Converting chinese character to Unicode

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding

Let's say I have a random Chinese character, 玩. I want to convert it to Unicode, which would be U+73A9. How could I do this in C#?

Comment: Where is this Chinese character coming from?  Keyboard input?  From a file on disk?  What codepage or encoding is used in that file? (Chinese Simplified, Chinese Traditional, or ??)  You need to know what encoding is used on the input bytes before you can meaningfully convert it to some other encoding.

Comment: Keyboard input, using UTF (16 I guess, that should have most of the characters), Simplified or traditional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take ***myChar*** as a char referencing your special character...

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} U+{1:x4} {2}", myChar, (int)myChar, (int)myChar);
```

Above we're outputting the character itself followed by the Unicode code point and then the integer value.

Reduce the format string and parameters to output only the "U+..." code...

```
Console.WriteLine("U+{0:x4}", (int)myChar);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome! Could you explain the code to me though? I understand you are just writing the U+, but what is `{0:x4}`? I know one of them is some specifier, so what is `:x4`?

Comment: The 'x4' outputs it as hex (x), 4 digits zero padded on the left.

Answer (score 2):

The characater 玩 is in Unicode.

If you have it in C# as 玩, then it's currently in UTF-16, which is one of the Unicode encoding forms.

If you are obtaining it from somewhere else you need to:

1. Find the encoding it is in.
2. Get the bytes (wrapped by a stream is nice).
3. Get of write an appropriate Encoder.
4. Use the encoder to get the string (wrapping the nice stream with a textreader is nicer).

Step 3 May be simple (oh, I just use that one!) or hard (darn, have to write it myself!) or somewhere in between (hey, anyone written one of these already?!)

Comment: What I mean is I want to turn the character into U+73A9

Comment: @Greg- thanks, but I want it the other way around. I want something like 玩 -> \u73a9

Answer (score 0):

A bit longer example, that follows the pattern in Jon Hanna's answer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace UnicodeDecodeConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char c = '\u73a9';
            char[] chars = {c};
            Encoding encoding = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode;
            byte[] decodeds = encoding.GetBytes(chars);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("U+");
            foreach (byte decoded in decodeds)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(decoded.ToString("x2"));
            }
            Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

--jeroen