# What does this C# string format mean?

Tags: c#, string

From my previous question, [Converting chinese character to Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571563/converting-chinese-character-to-unicode), I had a good answer but with some code I didn't understand:

`Console.WriteLine("U+{0:x4}", (int)myChar);`

Could anyone explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `0` indicates which positional argument to substitute. The `x` displays a hexadecimal number, the `4` has it display four digits.

For example, the character **ȿ** (LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH SWASH TAIL, codepoint 575) is printed as `U+023F` since 575<sub>10</sub> = 23F<sub>16</sub>.

Answer (score 7):

```
Console.WriteLine("U+{0:x4}", (int)myChar);
```

is the equivalent to the call:

```
Console.WriteLine("U+{0}", ((int)myChar).ToString("x4"));
```

In a format string, the `:` indicates that the item should be displayed using the provided format.  The `x4` part indicates that the integer should be printed in its hexadecimal form using `4` characters.  Refer to [standard numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Just saw this answer after I accepted the other one, but this one is very nice too!

Comment: I like Jeff's answer better than mine, to be honest!

Answer (score 1):

That will simply create the literal string "U+1234"... now if you are wanting to convert a unicode code point into a char, you want Convert.ToChar(myChar)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hkfdkcx.aspx