# Convert text to Numeric character references for HTML

Tags: c#, html, unicode

I need to convert chinese to Unicode in C# similar to [this converter](http://www.chinese-tools.com/tools/converter-unicode.html). For example

```
"大家好" -> "&#22823;&#23478;&#22909;"
```

Comment: And I need sleep... Besides the link you provided is 404

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571563/converting-chinese-character-to-unicode

Comment: This should be closed as a duplicate rather than “not a real question” (the question is real, though implicit).

Answer (score 3):

```
string input = "大家好";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += char.IsSurrogatePair(input, i) ? 2 : 1)
{
    int codepoint = char.ConvertToUtf32(input, i);
    sb.Append('&').Append('#').Append(codepoint).Append(';');
}

var result = sb.ToString();
// result == "&#22823;&#23478;&#22909;"
```

Comment: +1. It may be good idea to mention why you need IsSurrogatePair/ConvertToUtf32.

Comment: In short, a `char` in .NET is a 16-bit data type and `string`s are sequences of `char`s. There are around 2^21 Unicode code-points, though, so not all code-points can be stored in a single `char`. Code-points above 0x10000 are stored as pairs of two surrogate `char`s ("surrogate pair"). In contrast, numeric character references in HTML indicate code-points, so the sequence of `char`s has to be converted to a sequence of code-points first before you turn them into HTML.

Comment: Well you don't need both. You can just check in the loop body `if( codepoint > 0xFFFF) {i++}` and keep the standard for loop header.

Comment: Btw I like how something named like `ConvertToUTF32` is actually `CodePointAt` :X

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in *char* class enable to convert a char(in unicode I guess) into a utf-16 litera value, I think it might help you

```
public static int ConvertToUtf32(string s, int index)
```

Further referrence see at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2ys180b.aspx